# User Exit in T-Code co11n, code in CONFPP04 to Validate date field

Tags: date, hook, abap, exit, sap-erp

Just want to ask

I want to make a user exit for T-code co11n

The purpose of this user exit is to make sure that date value isn't left blank

(Make sure that date field must be filled)

I've try make it in CONFPP04 but when I get the date value (both date field is filled or not), the date value which is caught is 00000000

I wanna ask how to deal with it?
or can I have other solution?

Thanks :)

Comment: The question is very unclear. Please specify which system it is. SAP has many modules SD, MM, Banking, etc. Moreover the description does not say anything. If the date is initial it means it has value 00000000 which is the standard behaviour in SAP.

Comment: It's PP. Please post your code or explain which date field on the time ticket your looking for. 00000000, you found a date that is initial or not filled in, but is not blank or null

Answer (score 0):

You can go to system-->status from their you can get the program or screen name for that transaction 
then try to search **call customer function**

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, You just have to check if the date is not initial.

As I can see you caught the value '00000000'. Now, all you have to do is check if the date is initial, and if so display an error message:

IF date = '00000000'.
   MESSAGE e(XX).
ENDIF.

Anyways, have you check if you can set that field as mandatory from the customizing ? You probably don't have to do that User-Exit if you can set that from the customizing.

Comment: to theck for an initial date/value, please use `IF date IS INITIAL. MESSAGE e(XX). ENDIF.` instead.